# VBA Loop to copy/paste blocks of columns into another worksheet with dynamic range

Tags: vba, loops, dynamic

I usually find my answer here but I've been stuck on this one for several days now.
I'm working on 2 sheets, one with new data, and one with historical data.
On each sheet I have 'blocks' of columns, those blocks are always 4 columns wide, with a blank column in-between. And have different row length.
For example, there are data on column A to D, then a blank column, then data in column F to I,etc. as below:

```
Item1|     |     |     |     |Item2|     |     |     |
Title|Title|Title|Title|     |Title|Title|Title|Title|
data |data |data |data |     |data |data |data |data |
data |data |data |data |     |data |data |data |data |
     |     |     |     |     |data |data |data |data |
```

**Goal:** Need to check if the item number (ex: Cell A1 for the first block) is equal to the item number on the destination sheet (same cell A1).
Need to copy data from row 3 (first row with actual data) until the last row, for the first block of column, onto the 2nd sheet after the last row containing data. And create a loop for each block of columns until the last column of the source sheet.
**Issue:** The blocks of columns have different row length. Same thing on the destination sheet, each block have different row length. Which is why I need to use a dynamic range, for each block.
My code is here below, I managed to have it working for the first block of column by using the column letters, but it's not doing anything (no error message neither) when I try to use a dynamic range with variables, so I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.

```
Sub copydata()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim shta As Worksheet
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Set shta = wb.Sheets("source")
Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("target")
Dim c As Long
Dim LastCol As Long 'last column sheet source
lrws As Long 'last row of source column
frwt As Long 'first available row in target column
Dim rngs As Range
Dim rngt As Range
Const frsrc As Long = 3 'first row on source column to copy from

For c = 1 To LastCol
    If shta.Cells(1, c).Value = sht1.Cells(1, c).Value Then 'ensure data item are the same
    lrws = shta.Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
    frwt = sht1.Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    LastCol = shta.Cells(frsrc, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rngs = shta.Range(c & frsrc).Resize(lrws, 4) 'source range of first block of columns
    Set rngtg = sht1.Range(c & frwt & ":" & c & frwt).Resize(rngs.Rows.Count) 'target range for first block of column
    rntg.Value = rngs.Value
    c = c + 4 'move to the next block of column
    Else: MsgBox "Need to check table formatting"
    End If
Next c
    
End Sub
```

There might be a better/easier way of doing it, than moving a block of columns at a time, but that's the only way I could think about.
I'm fairly new to VBA, and would really appreciate any comments/feedback you may have.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Use `Cells` rather than `Range` which doesn't accept a number as the first argument.

Comment: Hi @SJR, are you referring to the `Range` I've used after I `Set` the range array?  
I've tried to do so but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Yes. `Range(c & frsrc)` will result in something like `Range(210)` which has no meaning. Use `Cells` as you have elsewhere already which is row, column and accepts numbers or letters.

Comment: I've tried your method, I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, or setting my sheets or variables incorrectly but there is absolutely nothing happening when I run the code..

Comment: It's probably just `cells(frsrc,c)` ?